# Camelot-py does not pull negative numbers into table from read_pdf() function

Tags: csv, pdf, python-3.8, python-camelot

Using:
Python 3.8.18
camelot-py[cv]

When extracting tables from a pdf using the read_pdf() function, I am able to get nearly all the data into a CSV but whenever a negative number is present in the PDF ( ex: -$5.67) it leaves the field blank. No errors, just missing data.

Ive tried looking at all the documentation including the API Reference, but I cant find anything relevant.  Does anyone have an idea of why this is happening and how it could be fixed?

https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#camelot.read_pdf